# round to higher multiple of 5

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

i am trying to round values to it's higher multiple of 5
For example:

```
df
values    rounded_values (expected column)
    10                10
    11                15
    13                15
    22                25
    21                25
    34                35  
    35                35
```

Comment: Can't you just use a simple function  ```lambda x: x if x%5==0 else x + (5 - x%5)```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df["rounded_values"] = ((df.values+4)//5)*5
print(df)
   values  rounded_values
0      10              10
1      11              15
2      13              15
3      22              25
4      21              25
5      34              35
6      35              35
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying container of a Pandas column is a numpy array, so you could just use numpy here:

```
import numpy as np

df['rounded_values'] = np.round_((np.ceil(df['values']/5)*5)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mod:

```
def round_to5(x):
    if x%5 == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return x + (5 - x%5)

df['round_values'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: round_to5(x))
```

Output is:

```
  values    round_values
0   10          10
1   12          15
2   24          25
3   27          30
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply, by first dividing by 5, then calling `math.ceil`, then multiplying by 5:

```
>>>import math
>>>round5 = lambda n: math.ceil(n / 5) * 5
>>> round5(22)
25
>>> round5(21)
25
>>> round5(35)
35
>>> round5(10)
10
>>> round5(11)
15
>>> round5(15)
15
```